# Calculator doesn't execute the operations

Tags: calculator, abap

I am trying to build a calculator in abap. The requirements are:

- Reads

  - two numbers (ex. 56.3 and 78.2)
  - a character from the following list: q, w, e, r, t
- Displays the result of the operation specified by the character

  - Addition for character q
  - Subtraction for character w
  - Multiplication for character e
  - Division for character r
  - Exponent for character t

I have created a table with the operations that I am using in the calculator.
The problem is when I execute the program it only prints my last option (else) "the operation is not possible".

Here's the code I wrote:

```
REPORT Z_CALCULATOR_V2.

TABLES: ZOPERATII.
DATA result type p decimals 2.
DATA Q type c.
DATA W like Q.
DATA E like Q.
DATA R like Q.
DATA T like Q.

PARAMETERS Nr_1 type p decimals 2 OBLIGATORY.
PARAMETERS Nr_2 like Nr_1 OBLIGATORY.
PARAMETERS Operatie LIKE zoperatii-operatie OBLIGATORY.


if Operatie = Q.
  result = Nr_1 + Nr_2.


elseif Operatie = W.
    result = Nr_1 - Nr_2.

elseif Operatie = E.

elseif Operatie = R.
        result = Nr_1 / Nr_2.

elseif Operatie = T.
       result = Nr_1 ** Nr_2.

else.
  WRITE 'The operation is not possible'.
  endif.
  write result.
```

Comment: Why do you use variables instead of literals like 'q' or 'w'? Your variables are empty when declaring. That's why the program runs into the else section.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....i am not sure what to answer, i was thinking the literals q or w ARE the variables ... what do you mean my variables are empty? cause the user will just provide values for them...or how do I make them NOT empty?

Comment: Well, they are not the same. Literals are described [here](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenliteral.htm) and variables [here](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapdata.htm).

Answer (score 1):

if you change the data declarations to:

```
DATA Q type c value 'Q'.
DATA W type c value 'W'.
DATA E type c value 'E'.
DATA R type c value 'R'.
DATA T type c value 'T'.
```

the code should run as you expect.  That said, you should read up on the documentation as suggested in the comments.